# Add View context menu item is gone

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I am going through Music Store tutorial (ASP.NET 3/Razor). After I have created the Home controller and Index action, I have right-clicked everywhere in Index action body (and declaration) and "Add View" does not show up.

I have tried Ctrl+M, Ctrl-V but it says this combination "is bound to command (Add View...) which is not currently available.".

Note: This is VS 2010; I had installed NDjango NuGet package which I thought caused this. But even after uninstalling that package the problem remains.

Comment: I have reset Visual Studio 2010 settings and the problem still stands.

Comment: Even after executing devenv.exe /resetsettings and devenv.exe /setup problem exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created another MVC 3 project and Add View menu item was available. I had not the time to uncover resolutions so re-created the project from ground up; and It worked! I don't know re-installing MVC 3 has any effect, but this seems to be the solution.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you were upgrading a website project from a previous version, but what I did was add {E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401}; to the list of ProjectGuids in the project file itself (you need to unload the project, make the edit, and then reload the project.

That worked for me.

Comment: Here is the line from my file. I had the same problem and reseting the type guids worked for me. <ProjectTypeGuids>{E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but when I look more closely, I saw that action method (in the case of music store tutorial HomeController.Index) returns string. Modify method to return ActionResult and then Add View menu item will be available.

Comment: Yes I changed it to `public ActionResult Index()` in the HelloWorldController and this worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling the MVC3 bits? I guess that's what adds the Add View and Goto View context menu items.

Comment: Do you still have MVC2 etc installed? Perhaps try reinstalling all MVC bits? Other than that I'm at a loss, just looked all the way through the Tools>Customize>Commands>Context menu>Editor Context Menu items and there is no reference to Add View/Goto View!

Comment: I re-created project from ground up; and It worked! I don't know re-installing MVC 3 has any effect, but this seems to be the solution!

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue and I read a post found here:

http://www.techiesweb.net/how-to-get-add-view-add-controller-menus-in-solution-explorer-when-converting-existing-asp-net-web-for-project-to-mvc/

Which helped me alot and i want to share it for you guys. Hope this will help you alot.

Answer (score 0):

If the function in the controller does not return ActionResult then the context menu will not show "Add View".